# How to setup IIS subdomain pointing to folder on remote machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net

Im trying to serve static content through a subdomain.  The physical folder is shared on a second machine in the same local domain.

How do I safely setup permissions on the shared folder so that when i do something like:

src="subdomain.domain.com/Image1.png" I wont get access denied?

IN IIS I have subdomain.domain.com as a separate website.

EDIT: AWOULD THERE BE ANY PERFORMANCE DIFFERENCE IF INSTEAD OF CREATING A NEW WEBSITE FOR THE SUBDOMAIN, I ADDED A VIRTUAL DIRECTORY IN ORIGINAL SITE TO ACCESS THE REMOTE CONTENT?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions will depend on who is accessing this site, will it be only local users or remote(outside) clients.

If everything was on that local machine than the Anonymous Account would just get Read & Execute permissions, but i think on the share you must add the Everyone group with Read & Execute permissions

I personally don't like this idea of over network, performance & reliability wise.

I don't understand your last edit, but I would run the sub-domain on a different application pool, goodluck